# How should the output layer be set when using the LSTM layer?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

time step = 100
features = 4

I want to have a time step of 100 and the number of features of 4 and the last layer of the model as 1. But the attempt, but the error. How should we solve this problem? Should LSTM layers be added?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape = (100, 4)))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Dense(8))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.add(Dense(1))


model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr = 0.01), loss = 'mean_squared_error',metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs = 300, batch_size=100, verbose = 1, shuffle=True, callbacks=[early_stopping_callback, checkpointer], 
      validation_data=(X_test,Y_test))
```

and this is error...

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_56 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (4,)
```

Comment: Reduce the number of layers, and check the array size at each layer.

Comment: @abunickabhi yes right!

Comment: What's the shape of your `Y_train`?